# Why user-defined whatsit kicks out kerning?

Tags: luatex, kerning, callback

I ran in to trouble marking math content (in this example I'll be talking about simple superscript) with user-defined whatsit. Font kerning does not appear if whatsit is in between characters where normally kern would be placed.

Marking superscript is done in `mlist_to_hlist` callback and later (in `pre_output_filter` callback) I'm processing node list and I need to know where superscript begins/ends to do *something* with it.

luatex documentation mentions not much about user-defined whatsis but it seems they should be virtual and should not influence the output. I tried to fix kerning by creating it with `node.kerning()` and adding to the right place but then I need some how to recalculate all the outer boxes (hlist's, vlist's). 
Thought using `kerning` callback I could do something but it seems it has now access to display math converted nodes. I see only `hlist` node but it has no head.

Question: is there a safe way to add user-defined whatsit in math without influencing the output. Or is there another way to mark some positions in math nodes and get them in pre_output_filter.

**test.tex**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{luatexbase}
\directlua{dofile("mathsup.lua")}

\begin{document}
\loggingall
$$ xdf$$

$$ xdf^2 $$
\end{document}
```

**mathsup.lua**

```
local USER_MARK   = node.new("whatsit","user_defined")
USER_MARK.type    = 115   
USER_MARK.value   = "0"   

local function tag_superscript (h, d, p)
    for n in node.traverse(h) do
        if n.sup then
            -- tagging superscript Begin and End
            local A = node.copy(USER_MARK)
            A.value = "pre_superscript"
            h = node.insert_before(h, n, A)

            local B = node.copy(USER_MARK)
            B.value = "post_superscript"
            node.insert_after(h, n, B)    
        end
    end
    return node.mlist_to_hlist(h, d, p)
end
luatexbase.add_to_callback('mlist_to_hlist', tag_superscript, 'Tag superscript')
```

In output of the first display there is `\kern-1.66667`:

```
...\hbox(6.94444+1.94444)x15.22572, shifted 164.88715, direction TLT
....\OML/cmm/m/it/10 x
....\OML/cmm/m/it/10 d
....\kern-1.66667 (font)
....\OML/cmm/m/it/10 f
....\kern1.0764 (italic)
```

In output of the second display kern is missing:

```
...\hbox(8.64003+1.94444)x21.37852, shifted 161.81075, direction TLT
....\OML/cmm/m/it/10 x
....\OML/cmm/m/it/10 d
....\whatsit0="pre_superscript"
....\OML/cmm/m/it/10 f
....\kern1.0764 (italic)
....\hbox(4.51111+0.0)x4.48613, shifted -4.12892, direction TLT
.....\OT1/cmr/m/n/7 2
....\whatsit0="post_superscript"
```

Comment: unrelated but you shouldn't normally do `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` with luatex and only need `\usepackage{luatexbase}` if you need compatibility with early lualatex

Comment: What are you trying to do in the end? (I just looked at this callback and so I'm  curious).

Comment: Also, you shouldn't use `$$` for maths in LaTeX (deprecated since sometime in the 1980s, I think).

Comment: That is just an example. I'm trying to tag a mathml.  `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` I use to suppress OTF fonts (because I use DVI viewer).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use node attributes to mark some nodes:

```lua
local sup_attr = luatexbase.new_attribute("sup_attr")

local glyph_id = node.id "glyph"
local hlist_id = node.id "hlist"
local vlist_id = node.id "vlist"

local function tag_superscript (h, d, p)
    for n in node.traverse(h) do
        if n.sup then
          node.set_attribute(n.sup, sup_attr, 1)
        end
    end
    return node.mlist_to_hlist(h, d, p)
end

local uchar = unicode.utf8.char
local function traverse_hlist(head, groupcode)
  for n in node.traverse(head) do
    local id = n.id
    if id == glyph_id  and node.has_attribute(n, sup_attr) then
      print("here is a subscript", uchar(n.char), node.get_attribute(n, sup_attr))
      -- do your stuff here
      node.unset_attribute(n, sup_attr)
    elseif id == hlist_id or id == vlist_id then
      traverse_hlist(n.head)
    end
  end
  return head
end


luatexbase.add_to_callback('mlist_to_hlist', tag_superscript, 'Tag superscript')
luatexbase.add_to_callback("pre_linebreak_filter", traverse_hlist, "Find superscript")
luatexbase.add_to_callback("hpack_filter", traverse_hlist, "Find superscript")
luatexbase.add_to_callback("vpack_filter", traverse_hlist, "Find superscript")
```

Custom attribute is defined using `luatexbase.new_attribute("sup_attr")`, it is set in math nodes which has the `sup` field. The attribute is set directly to the node in `sup` field.

In the node traversing callback, we are looking for glyphs which have set our attribute. You can do your stuff at this place. The attribute is then removed, in order to prevent multiple executions of the node processing.

Note that your particular example is processed by the `vpack_filter`, because `pre_linebreak_filter` doesn't process display math.

Comment: That was my first attempt to tag math nodes with attributes  but I git it  very messy. I agree that it would be more safe.

Comment: I think attributes are the right way to go, maybe you should give it another try